# Trying to do hardware H264 encoding with gstreamer on a Raspberry Pi 4B

Tags: hardware, streaming-video, gstreamer, h264, video-input

I am attempting to do hardware-accelerated H264 encoding on a Raspberry Pi 4B. I am running bullseye with an aarch64 kernel and a 32-bit userland:

```
ben@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
ben@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 6.1.21-v8+ #1642 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 17:24:16 BST 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux
ben@raspberrypi:~ $ file $(which file)
/usr/bin/file: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, BuildID[sha1]=46998c6200b7bcc2d6b1539b82d4044903017bb4, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
```

I'm attempting this without legacy camera support (which I have disabled), and I have placed `dtoverlay=ov5647` in `/boot/config.txt`. Here is my gstreamer pipeline:
`gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=foo.mp4`

And here is the resulting error:

```
en@raspberrypi:~ $ gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=foo.mp4
0:00:00.001724829  3297   0xa5a680 WARN         GST_PERFORMANCE gstbuffer.c:496:_priv_gst_buffer_initialize: No 64-bit atomic int defined for this platform/toolchain!
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
0:00:00.078681235  3297   0xc0a648 WARN                 v4l2src gstv4l2src.c:694:gst_v4l2src_query:<v4l2src0> Can't give latency since framerate isn't fixated !
0:00:00.078756808  3297   0xc0a648 WARN              aggregator gstaggregator.c:2046:gst_aggregator_query_latency_unlocked:<mp4mux0> Latency query failed
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
0:00:00.079713091  3297   0xc0a648 WARN                 v4l2src gstv4l2src.c:694:gst_v4l2src_query:<v4l2src0> Can't give latency since framerate isn't fixated !
0:00:00.079763109  3297   0xc0a648 WARN              aggregator gstaggregator.c:2046:gst_aggregator_query_latency_unlocked:<mp4mux0> Latency query failed
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
0:00:00.080218473  3297   0xc0a648 WARN                 v4l2src gstv4l2src.c:694:gst_v4l2src_query:<v4l2src0> Can't give latency since framerate isn't fixated !
0:00:00.080253992  3297   0xc0a648 WARN              aggregator gstaggregator.c:2046:gst_aggregator_query_latency_unlocked:<mp4mux0> Latency query failed
New clock: GstSystemClock
0:00:00.080297213  3297   0xc0a680 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3127:gst_base_src_loop:<v4l2src0> error: Internal data stream error.
0:00:00.080336342  3297   0xc0a680 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3127:gst_base_src_loop:<v4l2src0> error: streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3127): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
0:00:00.080563154  3297   0xc0a648 WARN                 v4l2src gstv4l2src.c:694:gst_v4l2src_query:<v4l2src0> Can't give latency since framerate isn't fixated !
0:00:00.080594820  3297   0xc0a648 WARN              aggregator gstaggregator.c:2046:gst_aggregator_query_latency_unlocked:<mp4mux0> Latency query failed
Execution ended after 0:00:00.000594344
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
0:00:00.080663116  3297   0xc0a648 FIXME               basesink gstbasesink.c:3384:gst_base_sink_default_event:<filesink0> stream-start event without group-id. Consider implementing group-id handling in the upstream elements
0:00:00.080744133  3297   0xc0a648 WARN                GST_PADS gstpad.c:4303:gst_pad_peer_query:<mp4mux0:src> could not send sticky events
0:00:00.080804632  3297   0xc0a648 WARN              aggregator gstaggregator.c:607:gst_aggregator_push_mandatory_events:<mp4mux0:src> Sending caps event failed
0:00:00.080841613  3297   0xc0a648 WARN                   qtmux gstqtmux.c:3076:gst_qt_mux_start_file:<mp4mux0> Robust muxing requires reserved-moov-update-period to be set
0:00:00.080954816  3297   0xc0a648 WARN              aggregator gstaggregator.c:607:gst_aggregator_push_mandatory_events:<mp4mux0:src> Sending caps event failed
0:00:00.080993148  3297   0xc0a648 FIXME             aggregator gstaggregator.c:1365:gst_aggregator_aggregate_func:<mp4mux0> Subclass should call gst_aggregator_selected_samples() from its aggregate implementation.
Freeing pipeline ...
```

What am I doing wrong? I've found lots of information on the web about hardware encoding on rpi, but it all seems out-of-date for the latest hardware and software.